# Maximal Linearly Independent Sets (Hoffman Kunze)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble with part of a proof in Hoffman Kunze. It begins, "... Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a commuting family of diagonalizable normal operators on a finite dimensional inner product space $V$. Let $\{T_1,...,T_m\}$ be a maximal linearly independent subset of $\mathcal{F}$..."

My question is, if $S$ is just a subset of a vector space, does $S$ necessarily have a maximal set of linearly independent vectors? In this case $\mathcal{F}$ is not generically a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V)$. Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ does have a maximal set of linearly indpendent vectors. Then span$\{T_1,...,T_m\}=\mathcal{F}$. Otherwise, $\exists f\in\mathcal{f}$ such that $f\not\in$ span$\{T_1,...,T_m\}\implies \{T_1,...,T_m,f\}$ is linearly independent which is a contradiction. So span$\{T_1,...,T_m\}=\mathcal{F}$ but since span is a subspace, then $\mathcal{F}$ is a subspace? Can anyone see what's wrong with this

Comment: Your argument only works for one direction of your span equality. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer I'm not sure what you mean. I should have mentioned that the $T_i$ are all in $\mathcal{F}$, or at least, I think that's what the authors mean. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: $\mathcal{F}$ is not necessarily a subspace. ​ ​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the span of **all** the elements in $\;\mathcal F\;,\;\;\langle\mathcal F\rangle$ . We know that $\;\langle\mathcal F\rangle\le End\,(V)\;$ , and also $\;\dim V=n\implies \dim End\, (V)=n^2<\infty\;$ .

Thus, $\;\langle\mathcal F\rangle\;$ is a subspace of a finite dimensional space so it has a basis which is also a maximal linearly independet set in $\;\langle\mathcal F\rangle\;$ and thus also in $\;\mathcal F\;$ .

Nothing's wrong with what you did: you just still didn't have *a basis* of $\;\langle\mathcal F\rangle\;$ , and also when you write $\;Span\,\{T_1,..., T_n\}=\mathcal F\;$ it in fact should be $\;Span\,\{T_1,...,T_n\}=\langle\mathcal F\rangle\;$ , as $\;\mathcal F\;$ isn't necessarily a subspace...as you said.

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense. Thank you very much.